# How to customize markers generated by setting stopover to true

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using `Google Map API` to display my route. I have an array of way points. Because I need to use `optimizeWaypoints`, so all `stopover` of all markers have to be set to `true`. By doing that, `Google Map` automatically creates a marker at each way point, with `click event` to show `info window`.

My question is, how can I customize those auto generated markers? For example, if I want to change the content of those `info windows`, what should I do?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Check google.maps.DirectionsRendererOptions and markerOptions.

Comment: I've checked the DirectionsRendererOptions and see there is an option called `infoWindow`, but it only receives one `InfoWindow` object. So, how can I create an `infoWindow` for each marker?

Answer (score 0):

There is no implemented option to customize these markers.

The content of the infoWindow may be modified by using a custom infoWindow(via the `infoWindow`-option of the DirectionsRenderer ), listen to the `domready`-event of the InfoWindow and modify the `content`....but this InfoWindow will also be used by the origin/destination-markers, there is no way to differentiate these markers from waypoint-markers.

The best you can do is to use the `suppressMarkers`-option to hide the automatically generated markers, and create the markers on your own based on the `DirectionsResult`.

Comment: So, how can I quickly create the marker like the generated ones (with A, B, C, D in order). I just want to modify the info window, not the marker itself.